# ant throwing an error "java returned 1"

Tags: java, ant

So I am trying to build a repository and on using "ANT", i get the following error:

```
Copying 1851 files to F:\GitHub\appinventor-sources\appinventor\appengine\build\war         CheckYaClientApp: YaClientApp: 
[java] Jan 14, 2015 10:33:52 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
[java] WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5. 
[java] Compiling module com.google.appinventor.YaClient 
[java] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error 
[java] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to write to byte cache 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.writeByteArray(DiskCache.java:219) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.(CompiledClass.java:106) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.createCompiledClass(JdtCompiler.java:266) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:239) 
[java] at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:718) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:248) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:463) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:388) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:373) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:246) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger (CompileTaskRunner.java:82) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177) 
[java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk 
[java] at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes0(Native Method) 
[java] at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(RandomAccessFile.java:520 ) 
[java] at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(RandomAccessFile.java:537) 
[java] at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.writeByteArray(DiskCache.ja va:216) 
[java] ... 18 more BUILD FAILED

F:\GitHub\appinventor-sources\appinventor\build.xml:16: The following error occu rred while executing this line: F:\GitHub\appinventor-sources\appinventor\appengine\build.xml:364: Java returned : 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: We have no idea what project you're compiling, the `build.xml` file, etc. All I can say is that the error occurred while attempting to run a on a Java on a classfile. Did you compile this class file? What's the `<java>` task? In order to get your question answered, you need to provide more information.

Comment: I've just reformatted your error output, so it's at least readable. Next time, repipe your output to a file, then add four spaces to the beginning of each line. And, then paste it into Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

Your error message contains the answer to your question:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk

Moral of the story: always read the error messages, they're there for a reason.

Comment: but there is enough space in all the disks.that is what I could not figure out - that why is it still throwing the error

Comment: that definitely is not the issue.Although I did try to do an ant clean and then ant.

Comment: @user3630022 What makes you sure that it's definitely not the issue?  From the evidence provided, the contrary seems more likely...

Comment: @user3630022 This most likely is the issue.  Error messages don't typically lie.  Perhaps the file it attempted to write was too large, so the whole file wasn't written, leaving empty space.  Perhaps the process trying to write had a different "visibility" to the disk, meaning not enough space from it's point of view.   Perhaps you are writing the file across a temporarily unavailable network resource.  Sometimes it takes a bit of creative interpretation to determine how the error message makes sense; however, there are very few times when the error messages directly lie.

Answer (score 0):

apply -verbose before the target to get more details on the error, i ran into same issue could -verbose did help me to find the root cause.